# Refresh page request in angular-Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am new to `angularjs`. Here I have a problem, when I login in application and then I am on some page which requires the server response. So,

In my controller I do

```
if (localStorage.getItem('authToken') === null || localStorage.getItem('authToken') === undefined) {
        $state.go('default.login');
      } else {
     /// all other part of controller


$scope.loadReports = function () {
          $scope.loadingReports = true;
          if ($scope.documentType === "jobDescription") {
            $scope.showcheckbox = false;
            $scope.showSendButton = false;
          }
          var jdCurrentFileName = jdService.getjdUniqueId();
          uploadService.loadReports(uploadService.currentFileName, $scope.documentType, jdCurrentFileName)
            .then(function (response) {
},
            function (error) {
              $scope.loadingReports = false;
              $scope.errorMessage = error.status + " : " + error.statusText;
              if (error.status === 401) {
                loginService.authenticationError();
              }
            });
```

Now, what is happening here is that when I refresh a page then what ever data I had set in service using setter that all data get lost. So, while calling this service in services

```
loadReports: function (fileName, docType, jobId) {
                    var url = 'rez' + '/reports/' + docType + '/' + fileName + '/' + jobId;
                    var config = {};
                    config.headers = {
                        "X-AUTH-TOKEN": loginService.getAuthToken()
                    };
                    return $http.get(url, config)
                        .then(function (response) {
                            return response.data;
                        },
                        function (error) {
                            $log.error(error);
                            return $q.reject(error);
                        });
                },
```

If You see then jobId is coming from the service setter But when I refresh then all the service set values gets lost . SO, can any one please help me with this? How to do refresh requests in angular ?

Answer (score 0):

A single page application in AngularJS/Angular is not designed to accommodate browser refresh.
The values you need to retain after a browser refresh need to be stored in storage, `localstorage` or `sessionstorage`. use

**To Set**

```
localstorage.setItem("yourkey",value);  
sessionstorage.setItem("yourkey",value);
```

**To Retrive**

```
localstorage.getItem("yourkey");
sessionstorage.getItem("yourkey");
```

If you intent to refrest the data shown on a page by browser refresh, then you have to make the object listen to an event (the event that could cause your data to change)

Comment: So, Right now when I refresh the page then it goes to the login page .

Comment: The above is an idea for you to work with. Please store login token information in local or session storage as per your requirement and write your code so that the session will not expire on refresh.